# How to reduce my code length without changing concept?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

can Any one hep me on this. There are three servers. I want to assign a job to a server which has least Notstarted jobs. we want to consider the started jobs and not started jobs. ihave achieved this. But my code is very lengthy. I dont know how to minimize my code without changing my concept. Here is my code:

```
    public List<int> GetPaServer()
    {
        List<int> PaServers = new List<int>();
        using (PaEntities pa = new PaEntities())
        {
            var PaServer = from server in pa.AppPM_Pa_Server
                              where server.IsActive == true
                              select server.ServerId;
            foreach (var paServer in PaServer)
            {
                PaServers.Add(paServer);
            }
        }
        return PaServers;
    }


    //Method to get the serverid for each request.
    public int GetPaQueue()
    {
        using (PaEntities server = new PaEntities())
        {
            List<int> Paserver = new List<int>();
            Paserver = GetPaServer();
            string server1 = string.Empty;
            string server2 = string.Empty;
            string server3 = string.Empty;
            foreach (int paserver in Paserver)
            {
                if (paserver == 1)
                {
                    server1 = "active";
                }
                else if (paserver == 2)
                {
                    server2 = "active";
                }
                else if (paserver == 3)
                {
                    server3 = "active";
                }
            }
            int retVal = 0;

            // Get the Server NotStarted details here
            var NotStarted1 = (from serverID in server.AppPM_Pat
                               where serverID.Status == "NotStarted" && serverID.ServerId == 1
                               select serverID.ServerId).Count();
            var NotStarted2 = (from serverID in server.AppPM_Pat
                               where serverID.Status == "NotStarted" && serverID.ServerId == 2
                               select serverID.ServerId).Count();
            var NotStarted3 = (from serverID in server.AppPM_Pat
                               where serverID.Status == "NotStarted" && serverID.ServerId == 3
                               select serverID.ServerId).Count();

            // Get the  Server Started details here
            var server_Started1 = (from serverID in server.AppPM_Pat
                                   where serverID.Status == "Started" && serverID.ServerId == 1
                                   select serverID.ServerId).Count();
            var server_Started2 = (from serverID in server.AppPM_Pat
                                   where serverID.Status == "Started" && serverID.ServerId == 2
                                   select serverID.ServerId).Count();
            var server_Started3 = (from serverID in server.AppPM_Pat
                                   where serverID.Status == "Started" && serverID.ServerId == 3
                                   select serverID.ServerId).Count();

            //Get the server number for each  request
            //control comes here only when the server is active 
            if (server1 == "active" && server2 == "active" && server3 == "active")
            {
                if (NotStarted1 == 0 && NotStarted2 == 0 && NotStarted3 == 0)
                {
                    if ((server_Started1 > server_Started2) && (server_Started1 > server_Started3))
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 0 && server_Started2 == 0 && server_Started3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if ((server_Started2 > server_Started1) && (server_Started2 > server_Started3))
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if ((server_Started3 > server_Started1) && (server_Started3 > server_Started2))
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == server_Started2 && server_Started3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == server_Started3 && server_Started2 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started2 == server_Started3 && server_Started1 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                }
                //control comes here only when the third server is active after some time
                else if (NotStarted1 == NotStarted2 && NotStarted3 == 0)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                }
                else if ((NotStarted1 > NotStarted2) && NotStarted3 == 0)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                }
                else if ((NotStarted2 > NotStarted1) && NotStarted3 == 0)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                }
                //control comes here only when the first server is active after some time
                else if (NotStarted2 == NotStarted3 && NotStarted1 == 0)
                {
                    if (server_Started3 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started1 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                }
                else if ((NotStarted2 > NotStarted3) && NotStarted1 == 0)
                {
                    if (server_Started3 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started1 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                }
                else if ((NotStarted3 > NotStarted2) && NotStarted1 == 0)
                {
                    if (server_Started3 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started1 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                }
                //control comes here only when the second server is active after some time
                else if (NotStarted3 == NotStarted1 && NotStarted2 == 0)
                {
                    if (server_Started3 == 1 & server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                }
                else if ((NotStarted3 > NotStarted1) && NotStarted2 == 0)
                {
                    if (server_Started3 == 1 & server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                }
                else if ((NotStarted1 > NotStarted3) && NotStarted2 == 0)
                {
                    if (server_Started3 == 1 & server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 & server_Started2 == 1 & server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                }
                else if (NotStarted1 == 1 && NotStarted2 == 0 && NotStarted3 == 0)
                {
                    if ((server_Started1 > server_Started2) && (server_Started1 > server_Started3))
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 0 && server_Started2 == 0 && server_Started3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if ((server_Started2 > server_Started1) && (server_Started2 > server_Started3))
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if ((server_Started3 > server_Started1) && (server_Started3 > server_Started2))
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == server_Started2 && server_Started3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == server_Started3 && server_Started2 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started2 == server_Started3 && server_Started1 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                }
                else if (NotStarted1 == 1 && NotStarted2 == 1 && NotStarted3 == 0)
                {
                    if ((server_Started1 > server_Started2) && (server_Started1 > server_Started3))
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 0 && server_Started2 == 0 && server_Started3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if ((server_Started2 > server_Started1) && (server_Started2 > server_Started3))
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if ((server_Started3 > server_Started1) && (server_Started3 > server_Started2))
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == server_Started2 && server_Started3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == server_Started3 && server_Started2 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started2 == server_Started3 && server_Started1 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                }
                else if (NotStarted1 > NotStarted2 && NotStarted1 > NotStarted3)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        if (NotStarted2 > NotStarted3)
                        {
                            retVal = 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            retVal = 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (NotStarted2 > NotStarted3 && NotStarted2 > NotStarted1)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        if (NotStarted1 > NotStarted3)
                        {
                            retVal = 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            retVal = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (NotStarted3 > NotStarted1 && NotStarted3 > NotStarted2)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        if (NotStarted1 > NotStarted2)
                        {
                            retVal = 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            retVal = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (NotStarted1 == NotStarted2 && NotStarted2 == NotStarted3 && NotStarted1 == NotStarted3)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                }
                else if (NotStarted1 == NotStarted2 && NotStarted1 > NotStarted3 && NotStarted2 > NotStarted3)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                }
                else if (NotStarted2 == NotStarted3 && NotStarted2 > NotStarted1 && NotStarted3 > NotStarted1)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                }
                else if (NotStarted1 == NotStarted3 && NotStarted1 > NotStarted2 && NotStarted3 > NotStarted2)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                }                    
            }
            //control comes here only when server1 and server2 is active
            else if (server1 == "active" && server2 == "active")
            {
                if (NotStarted1 > NotStarted2)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                }
                else if (NotStarted1 == NotStarted2)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 0 && server_Started2 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 0 && server_Started2 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started2 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            //control comes here only when server3 and server2 is active
            else if (server2 == "active" && server3 == "active")
            {
                if (NotStarted2 > NotStarted3)
                {
                    if (server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                }
                else if (NotStarted2 == NotStarted3)
                {
                    if (server_Started2 == 0 && server_Started3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started2 == 0 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (server_Started2 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 2;
                    }
                }
            }
            //control comes here only when server1 and server3 is active
            else if (server1 == "active" && server3 == "active")
            {
                if (NotStarted1 > NotStarted3)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                }
                else if (NotStarted1 == NotStarted3)
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 0 && server_Started3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal = 3;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 0 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                    else if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (server_Started1 == 1 && server_Started3 == 1)
                    {
                        retVal = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use arrays to hold your servers, then loop over the arrays instead of repeating the same code for each server. In the loop you have a server AND its index, so you can omit changing just one number and the server while copying around the code. Rinse and repeat for NotStarted and the other values you calculate for each server.

Furthermore, it looks like you have an unrolled sorting algorithm in your code. If you combine a server and its NotStarted and other calculated values into a struct, you can just use an array of struct values and then sort it with a custom sorting function. Or use a LINQ expression. I'm still seven hours away from my dev PC, maybe I can hack something together this evening...

Comment: i can't get you. can you please give some more details

Comment: I'll skip that and just point to a nice answer on codereview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15975/how-to-reduce-my-code-length-without-changing-concept